# MongoDB 3.2 mongod.conf master/slave replication cant be configured via mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb

I need to setup master/slave replication for mongodb 3.2 server. Servers are Centos 6.7 and mongodb is latest 3.2 from offical RPMS. My /etc/mongod.conf is pretty much with default options from the RPM package. I know that 3.2 version is using YAML style for config file but no matter how i put master: enable , master: true or whatever mongod startup fails. I tryed to put the option into /etc/sysconfog/mongod file but this does not work also. My question is what is the correct way or command to put in to enable master mode. I putted --master into the startup script of the daemon and its looks OK but i don't think this is the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/)
You should try to use replication setting if any chance, and the master-slave behavior you want should be able to be [simulated using replication settings](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/#replica-set-equivalent).

Also you can convert your current master-slave nodes to a replica set, you can find the paragraph in the same page.

I guess you don't feel it's right because it's not recommended by mongodb to use this command line feature any more.